# VerticaPy kmeans fit without permissions to public schema

Tags: python, vertica

Using VerticaPy with a DB in which I don't have permissions to write to the 'public' schema (I have for a specific temp schema though), when trying to fit a kmeans model:

```
from verticapy.learn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans("sessions_kmeans", n_cluster = 10)
model.fit(url_onehot_by_session, [c for c in df.get_columns() if 'url' in c][:11])
```

I get the following error:

```
...PermissionDenied: Severity: ROLLBACK, Message: Permission denied for schema public, Sqlstate: 42501...
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't indicate any schema in the model name, it will try to write the model in the public schema.

To solve this issue please write:

```py
from verticapy.learn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans("my_schema.sessions_kmeans", n_cluster = 10)
model.fit(url_onehot_by_session, 
          [c for c in df.get_columns() if 'url' in c][:11])
```

Replace 'my_schema' by the schema of which you have writing access.

Best,

Badr

Comment: thanks, this soved the error, but now I get a new error:  "QueryError: Severity: ERROR, Message: Problem in kmeans.
Detail: Function public.random_init() does not exist, or permission is denied for public.random_init()....'

Comment: Hi. I am facing a similar issue where 'my_schema' is of the form 'firstname.lastname@company.com' (I do not have control over the name). Vertica returns this error: Database 'firstname' does not exist. Any tips?